# Split a Parent Vector to Overlapping Sub-vectors with Equal seb-vectors Length Except the Last Sub-vector in R

Tags: r, list, vector, merge, split

I want to split a parent vector into subvectors of equal lengths and overlapping suvectors such that if there exists a supposed last vector who would not make the specified subvector length to be merged with its penultimate. This question is a follow-up from @rawr comment [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63955082/r-split-a-vector-to-equally-overlapping-sub-vectors)

```
########Block function######################
blocks <- function(len, ov, n) {

  starts <- unique(sort(c(seq(1, n, len), seq(len-ov+1, n, len))))
  ends <- pmin(starts + len - 1, n)

  # truncate starts and ends to the first num elements
  num <- match(n, ends)
  head(data.frame(starts, ends), num)
}

########Moving block#############
vec = 1:17
len = 8
ov = ceiling(len/2)
b <- blocks(len, ov, length(vec))
with(b, Map(function(i, j) vec[i:j], starts, ends))
```

> [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63955082/r-split-a-vector-to-equally-overlapping-sub-vectors) 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

> [2] 5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12

> [3] 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16

> [4] 13 14 15 16 17

**What I want**

I want the last list that is not up to the specified subvector to be merged to the penultimate list like this:

> [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63955082/r-split-a-vector-to-equally-overlapping-sub-vectors) 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

> [2]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12

> [3]  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 13 14 15 16 17

Comment: Do you want to just append the last two together `out[[3]] <- unlist(out[3:4]);
 out[[4]] <- NULL`

Comment: @akrun, Error in unlist(out[3:4]) : object 'out' not found

Comment: sorry, I meant the `out <- with(b, Map(function(i, j) vec[i:j], starts, ends))`

Comment: yes, provided the last list is not up to the set sublist length, otherwise, the competed last will not be appended with the penultimate.

Comment: You can add a condition with `if/else` to the abovre

Comment: I have edited my question please, the last example was not practically correct, so I removed it.

Comment: Yes, it does help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a condition with `if`

```
out <- with(b, Map(function(i, j) vec[i:j], starts, ends))
l1 <- length(out)
if(length(out[[l1]]) < len) {
    out[[l1-1]] <- unlist(out[(l1-1):l1])
    out[[l1]] <- NULL
}
```

-output

```
out
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

[[2]]
[1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12

[[3]]
 [1]  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 13 14 15 16 17
```